# Do we have a limit for the number of configurations we create in AWS AppConfig application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, app-config, aws-app-config

I am creating an AWS AppConfig application for my team. we have tons of configurations which we want to move to AppConfig. Do we have any limit on how many configurations we can create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits for AWS AppConfig are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ssm.html). I think the one relevant to your question is:

> Maximum number of configuration profiles per application - **100**.